# Texture paint resolution stepping artefacts

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am currently painting a face bump map in blender. On the image you can see these lines that appear on for example the nose from the painted bump. The model is low res since this wouldnt change anything in the texture. Even without a brush texture these artifacts appear. I tested a 4k and an 8 k image but there was not even a difference..

Hope someone knows the problem.

Maybe one more: Is it better to paint the details of the skin or with sculpt and then bake an image?

[image]

32-Bit Float image 
[image]

Comment: The resolution depends on the Dyntopo's resolution.

Comment: No, i have a multires on it which is now on level 1 or so. Its a bump map i painted that is independent of the mesh resolution..

Comment: Can you test with Full Float image for bump instead of regular image depth? It isn't going to help by increasing 2k to 4k, but the bit depth is the usual suspect here.

Comment: I have added the test with a 32-bit float image for the bump. I really dont know why this is.. because its even without a texture brush like this..

Comment: So basically i fixed it by swapping out the default node setup from blender. The setup generated when you generate a map in texture paint is putting the bump map into the normal of a principle bsdf.. The fix was to put the map with a multiply math node into the displacement slot but that need actually geometry..  Either way i still want to know why this is happening to a 32 bit float image when its in the normal slot..??

Comment: Ou. Changing the interpolation mode from linear to smart in the image node is changing the result dramatically. Way better!